# Why use spring beans instead of object initialization

Tags: spring

I am trying to understand the idea of spring beans and why I should use them. If I create a bean and use it to print something out like this.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
Account acc = (Account)context.getBean("account");
acc.printAccName();
```

Why not just create an object of that class like this

```
Account acc2 = new Account();
acc.printAccName();
```

I have been watching some video's and did some reading but I did not get an answer why it is better.

Comment: Beyond Spring you should understand what the inversion of control is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

Comment: Familiarise yourself with the SOLID principles

Comment: Thanks for the resource I will read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually what you inject is business logic or services which typically is what changes in a system.

You are trying to inject a domain object `Account` these objects are not subject to change so it is okay to create the object via new. Perhaps, this is what it is confusing you.

The idea, is to let the container handle the instantiation of your logic or services that change regularly so you can swap them easily without having to open the client classes, because these might be already in production, tested and a developer could potentially introduce new bugs and break things. One way to avoid this is to follow a principle called [Open-Closed principle](http://cipriano-sanchez.herokuapp.com/blog/open-closed-principle.html#.WsKuTNNuaRs). Then you code to abstractions so you can easily inject concrete implementations via dependency injection.

Imagine the following escenario. For a bookstore, you have different implementations of how to save a book into a database e.g. using JDBC `BookServiceJDBCImpl`, or using an ORM `BookServiceHibernateImpl` etc..

```
    // Create & get the Spring container, where you configure your implementations
    // e.g. bookServiceJDBC, or bookServiceHibernate
    ApplicationContext container = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

    // the container loads the appropriate bean say bookServiceHibernate
    BookService bookService = (BookService) container.getBean("bookService");

    //Create a new book this is a domain object usually you use new
    Book newBook = new Book("1234", "Spring in Action","Rod Johnson");
    //Now save the book using the implementation defined in the 
    //container 
    bookService.registerNewBook(newBook);
```

This is how part of the container file may look like, in here you define the concrete implementation:

```
<bean id="bookService" class="service.BookServiceHibernateImpl"/>
```

By letting the container handle this you could inject different implementations without having to touch the client class or even knowing which implementation will be passed.

Check this [Dependency Injection blog post](http://cipriano-sanchez.herokuapp.com/blog/dependency-injection-with-spring.html#.WsKmE9NuaRs) it explains a way to achieve it using Spring.

Bare in mind that in Spring you can use java annotations or xml, and that there are different ways to inject dependencies e.g. via get/set, constructors etc this is just an illustrative example of the general DI concept. The design is up to the developer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer just  1 thing I am not sure about is. By letting the container handle this you could inject different implementations without having to touch the class isn't that just like polymorphism?

Comment: Exactly! You define your methods in an interface or abstract class. Then you use that interface or abstract class as type and inject an implementation of that interface which should have that method implemented

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why you would use beans is to aid testing.

> We also extract the RestTemplate into a @Bean to make it easier to
>   test (it can be mocked more easily that way). [Link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)